# Кавычки и тире нужны ли?

Tags: пунктуация

Совчонки, умные, родимые, родненькие, скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно.

1. «На протяжении веков» значит «на века».
2. На протяжении веков значит на века.
3. На протяжении веков – значит на века.
4. «На протяжении веков» – значит «на века».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Я выбираю  первый вариант: **«На протяжении веков» значит** (означает) **«на века».**

Это **пояснение** значений словосочетаний. Тире этом случае представляется лишним. Но сами словосочетания желательно как-то **выделить.**

2. Без кавычек возможен художественный текст. Например, он может выглядеть так: ***На века — значит на долгие времена.***

Здесь "значит" является **связкой**, поэтому нужно тире.